# How to get Firestore document fields that have a dynamic name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I use [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore)

In order to get the values from a document I usually represented them with a `Class`, for example:

```
public class FirestoreDoc
{
    public string key { get; set; }
}

firestoreDoc.ToObject<FirestoreDoc>().key;
```

Right now I have a specific problem. The name of the keys of the document are dynamically added by the user of the app. It's easy to obtain the key names from the document, but since I can't dynamically add class members to the `Class` how can I obtain their corresponding values?

**edit**:

Some additional information.

The fields I try to get are of type `array` and they store `reference` to other database documents.

Here is what I tried:

`var referenceList = firestoreDoc.Data[customKey];`

With that line **I succeed to get the value of the specific key**, but I still have two issues:

- I can't iterate over the values of the list I get,
- The values of the List are of type `string` and not `IDocumentReference` so I can't call the `GetAsync()` method on them to get the referenced documents.

For the second issue I tried  a cast:

`var referenceList = (List<IDocumentReference>)firestoreDoc.Data[customKey];`

but the result of the cast is an error:
`System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

Comment: Why you make the users to set the key name? Usually, you can use the queries to get the key names. You can check this article about [Simple queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT

Because the custom key names are a unique identifier that is also used as a document id for documents in another collection in the database, it makes sense to be user defined. I have already got the key names. I didn't have any issue with that. My problem is how to get the value that is associated with these custom key names. I will edit my post to give an update for what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after trying different approaches here is the solution:

```
var referenceList = (IEnumerable<Object>)firestoreDoc.Data[customKey];

foreach (var reference in referenceList)
{
     var referredDoc = await ((IDocumentReference)reference).GetAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hello @costas, could you place share what Type are using to get the document snapshot? I'm still stuck trying to get dynamic field names. I'm using this library: https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase

I have tried a lot of things without luck:  var documentReference = CrossFirebaseFirestore.Current.GetDocument(path);
        var document = await documentReference.GetDocumentSnapshotAsync<Dictionary<object, object>>();

Any hint is always welcome! thank you :)

Comment: @acido

What exactly is your problem? Do you have a problem with getting the `document` or the `field` data?

For the plug-in I use, the correct type is `IDocumentSnapshot`, but that's plug-in dependent. Also do yo really use dynamic field names? The specific issue I had was that the field names in my case are user defined. If you don't have user defined field names you can just use [a class to represent your document and its fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), then call `doc.ToObject<ClassName>().fieldName`

Comment: I posted my issue on detail here: https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/159 @costas , yes I use dynamic field name because, the field name is the Id of another document.

Comment: OK. So you indeed use dynamic field names. Try these 3 things: 1. Use the same casts I used. You have to find first the equivalent type of `IDocumentSnapshot` for your plug-in in order to proceed. 2. Switch to the plug-in I use, in case you don't have to change a big part of your code. Then follow the solution I used. 3. Wait for an answer from GitHub. There is a chance that the plug-in you use has a specific way to achieve the desired result.